# Dispatching multiple actions using redux-thunk updates component only once

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-thunk

I'm using `redux-thunk` for dispatching multiple action from one dispatch within a component.

```js
export function fetchQuestions() {
  return function(dispatch, getState) {
    dispatch({type: "QUESTION_FETCH_PENDING"});
    axios.get(`http://${API_ROOT}/api/questions/list`, {
        headers: {'JWT': getState().users.token}
    })
    .then((response) => {               
        //if registration is successful tell it to reducer and authorize user
        dispatch({type: "QUESTION_FETCH_SUCCESS", payload: response});
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        if (err.response.data == "login") {
            dispatch(unauthorizedRequest());
        }

        dispatch({
            type: "QUESTION_FETCH_FAIL",
            payload: err
        });
    });
  }
}
```

The problem is that I want component to be updated on each dispatch that are inside of wrapping dispatch. They all proceed to reducer, and I can see them logged in console.

[image]

But that does not happen, component is only updated after first dispatch.
You can see, `"FEED RENDER"` message that is called each time `render()` called, and it is not called after remaining dispatches.

Thank you in advance!

UPDATE 1: Here is code for my reducer

```js
export default function reducer(state={
questions: [],
questionPending: false,
questionSuccess: false,
questionFetching: false,
questionFetched: false,
error: null
}, action) {
    switch(action.type) {
        case "QUESTIONS_FETCH_PENDING": {
            return {...state, questionFetching: true, questionFetched: false}
        }
        case "QUESTIONS_FETCH_SUCCESS": {
            return {...state, questionFetching: false, questionFetched: true, questions: action.payload}
        }
        case "QUESTIONS_FETCH_FAIL": {
            return {...state, questionFetching: false, questionFetched: false, error: action.payload}
        }
        case "QUESTION_ADD_PENDING": {
            return {...state, questionPending: true, questionSuccess: false}
        }
        case "QUESTION_ADD_SUCCESS": {
            return {...state, questionPending: false, questionSuccess: true}
        }
        case "QUESTION_ADD_FAIL": {
            return {...state, questionPending: false, questionSuccess: false}
        }
    }

    return state;
}
```

And for injecting store, I simply use `@connect` decorator:

```js
@connect((store) => {
return {
        questions: store.questions,
        isAuth: store.users.isAuth
    };
})
```

Problematic component:

```js
export default class Feed extends React.Component {

componentWillMount() {
    this.props.dispatch(fetchQuestions());
}

componentWillUpdate() {
    console.log(this.props);
    if (!this.props.isAuth) {
        this.props.router.push('/auth');
    }
}

logout() {
    this.props.dispatch(logoutUser());
}

render() {
    console.log("FEED RENDER!");

    let questions = this.props.questions.questions.map((question) => {<questionFeed question={question}/>});

    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={this.logout.bind(this)}>LOGOUT</button>
            THIS IS FEED!
        </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: It really depends on your reducer and `mapStateToProps`. Could you provide the code for these?

Comment: @OB3 Hey, thank you for comment. I edited question and inserted all related code

Comment: There's a typo: you're dispatching QUESTION_FETCH_FAIL, but your reducer handles QUESTIONS_FETCH_FAIL

Comment: @OB3, OMG, I'm so sorry. For some reason, I assumed, if action has been logged via `redux-logger`, it has reached the reducer. I forgot that it's only a middleware.

Anyways, thank you very much for spending your time, and sorry for such a stupid mistake

Comment: @OB3, Do you think I should delete question, because it has no value for other users? Or should I post the answer?

Comment: No problem. I would keep it as is, it might be useful to some.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was simple **TYPO**: the names of actions didn't match to ones that are in reducers.

You can see I was dispatching `QUESTION_FETCH_FAIL` and `QUESTION_FETCH_SUCCESS`, but handling `QUESTIONS_FETCH_FAIL` and `QUESTIONS_FETCH_SUCCESS`.

**SOLUTION**: According to best practices of `redux`, you should always store action names in variables and share them with reducer.

**NOTE**: Don't fall to same dellusion as me, logged action in console does not mean it has reached the reducer

**SPECIAL THANKS**: To @OB3 for noting typo